# Large http Post with Golang and PostgreSQL make error

Tags: postgresql, http, go

I'm creating API using Golang.

When I tested with Postman, I can see api and postgresql work well.

But, when I started to test with Jmeter, I sent 10000 posts simultaneously.

A few posts make an error. Like this

```
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

There is an error in the line that makes db row.

I'm currently using gorm library for mapping objects.

Below code is makes error part.

```
var dbClient *gorm.DB
dbClient.Create(&{...object something})
```

Comment: You may be exceeding database connection limits, or open files limit.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Is increasing max_connections a good way? I don't know well backend knowledge...

Comment: That might take care of the db connection issue, if that's the issue. You have to find out the root cause. That was just a guess, and many things might be wrong here.